# Not able to print the variable that stores an extracted value from html file

Tags: python

Trying to print the extracted info from a html file, variable "ac" stores the extracted content(Nucleotide Id, eg:224589800) but the function exits without printing the variable.

```
import re
import urllib2
def sr():
    a = raw_input('Enter Gene Id:')
    b = int(a)
    s = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=s','r')
    h = s.read()
    s.close()
    acc = re.search('gi=(.+?)&amp',h) #Extraction of Nucleotide Id from html file
    if acc:
            ac = acc.group(1)
            print ac
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `gi=` anywhere within the source of that page. Is there a different URL we should be looking at? http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/224589800 perhaps?

Comment: check dis page http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=6323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to write `s = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term='+a,'r')` in the respective line. It then worked for me when I typed in Gene ID: 6232

You forgot to pass the input to the search function.